# Firebase-perf conflicting with let plugin

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, firebase-performance

We were recently asked to implement "Firebase Performance Monitoring" on an Android app, but it's been causing us lots of different problems. The app used to work just fine, but upon adding "firebase-perf", it compiles, but then on runtime we found out the [Let plugin](https://github.com/canelmas/let) stopped working, every permission defined with the @AskPermission annotation is simply ignored.

Looking through the gradle build output, I stumbled upon this stack-trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expecting .,<, or ;, but found firebaseperf while unpacking <K:Ljava/lang/Object;>Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/firebase-perf/zzw<TK;>;
    at org.aspectj.util.GenericSignatureParser.parseClassTypeSignature(GenericSignatureParser.java:204)
    at org.aspectj.util.GenericSignatureParser.parseAsClassSignature(GenericSignatureParser.java:56)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.UnresolvedType.forGenericTypeSignature(UnresolvedType.java:274)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.addSourceObjectType(BcelWorld.java:482)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.addSourceObjectType(BcelWorld.java:456)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.addAspectsFromJarFile(BcelWeaver.java:263)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.addLibraryJarFile(BcelWeaver.java:236)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.initBcelWorld(AjBuildManager.java:874)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.performBuild(AjBuildManager.java:249)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.batchBuild(AjBuildManager.java:185)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.ajc.AjdtCommand.doCommand(AjdtCommand.java:112)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.ajc.AjdtCommand.runCommand(AjdtCommand.java:60)
    at org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main.run(Main.java:371)
    at org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at com.canelmas.let.LetPlugin$_apply_closure2_closure3.doCall(LetPlugin.groovy:66)
    ...
```

I've seen some similar cases here and there but couldn't find a solution yet. The way I see it, it looks like a conflict between differing versions of aspectjs, defined in different classpaths.

This is the relevant part of out project-level gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath group: 'org.tmatesoft.svnkit', name: 'svnkit', version: '1.7.11'
        classpath('com.canelmas.let:let-plugin:0.1.11')
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5'
    }
}
```

And these are the firebase dependencies we have defined in the app-level gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.2.3'
}
```

Does anyone have an idea of a possible fix?

**EDIT:** There was someone in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50504933/java-lang-illegalstateexception-expecting-or-but-found-firebaseperf-whi), who claimed to have solved the problem with the code below, but I have no idea how to actually use it. Could anyone more Gradle-savvy be able to explain where is this declaration supposed to go and what I'm supposed to do with it?

I tried placing it many different places of my gradle file but I'm getting this error: "No such property: classpath for class: org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile"

```
def filtered_class_filetree = javaCompile.classpath.asFileTree.filter {
    !it.canonicalPath.contains("firebase-perf")
}
```

Comment: You should contact Firebase support directly with this issue.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Comment: I tried, but they replied as I feared, saying the problem is in the Let plugin, thus, out of their support coverage, and recommended I ask in SO. Fml...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If multiple libraries are compiling different versions of `aspectj` (or any other dependency), you can always force (or ignore) the ones you want like below:

```
implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7', { // this will remove aspectj dependencies from firebase
    exclude group: 'org.aspectj', module: 'aspectjrt'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'aspectjtools'
  })
```

You can also force aspect's version like below (beside your dependencies, in the module):

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:x.x.x'
}
```

To answer your last question:

> I tried placing it many different places of my gradle file but I'm
>   getting this error: "No such property: classpath for class:
>   org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile"

You can access java compiler (and classpath) using `applicationVariants` in `android` block inside your module:

```
  // inside your android module 
  android {
       //...
       applicationVariants.all {
       variant ->
         variant.javaCompiler.classpath = variant.javaCompiler.classpath.filter {
           !it.canonicalPath.contains("firebase-perf")
         }
     }
  }
```

Comment: The dependency hell was just my initial supposition. I tried doing those excludes already but the real problem was in the classpath, which means your last solution worked PERFECTLY! You get the cake ;)

Comment: Are there any side-effects to this solution though? Will firebase-perf still be compiled?

Comment: It will be compiled if it is provided somewhere else (from another library, or your own project).

Comment: The issue that you encountered, arises when someone creates a library, and "provides" another library, instead of just depending on it and let the user provide it itself, so when Gradle wants to compile all of the dependencies, it has two or more versions of the library in the class path.