# Running AspectJ and Firebase Performance Monitoring in Gradle builds

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, aspectj, firebase-performance

## Problem statement

I want to use AspectJ in an Android build with Gradle whilst instrumenting the built app with Firebase Performance Monitoring.

Unfortunately the build fails in the DEX merge step with `Type android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Default is defined multiple times: ...`

### Findings

In `app/build/ajc-transform.log` I found:

```
Wed Jul 22 07:55:14 CEST 2020
ABORT
    
Exception thrown from AspectJ 1.9.4

This might be logged as a bug already -- find current bugs at
  http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?product=AspectJ&component=Compiler

Bugs for exceptions thrown have titles File:line from the top stack, 
e.g., "SomeFile.java:243"

If you don't find the exception below in a bug, please add a new bug
at http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=AspectJ
To make the bug a priority, please include a test program
that can reproduce this exception.
Expecting .,<, or ;, but found firebaseperf while unpacking <MessageType:Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/firebase-perf/zzdz<TMessageType;TBuilderType;>;BuilderType:Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/firebase-perf/zzdy<TMessageType;TBuilderType;>;>Ljava/lang/Object;Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/firebase-perf/zzgr;
```

In the project root there is a `ajcore.log`:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expecting .,<, or ;, but found firebaseperf while unpacking <MessageType:Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/firebase-perf/zzdz<TMessageType;TBuilderType;>;BuilderType:Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/firebase-perf/zzdy<TMessageType;TBuilderType;>;>Ljava/lang/Object;Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/firebase-perf/zzgr;
    at org.aspectj.util.GenericSignatureParser.parseClassTypeSignature(GenericSignatureParser.java:204)
    at org.aspectj.util.GenericSignatureParser.parseFieldTypeSignature(GenericSignatureParser.java:155)
    at org.aspectj.util.GenericSignatureParser.parseFormalTypeParameter(GenericSignatureParser.java:130)
    at org.aspectj.util.GenericSignatureParser.parseAsClassSignature(GenericSignatureParser.java:51)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.UnresolvedType.forGenericTypeSignature(UnresolvedType.java:275)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.addSourceObjectType(BcelWorld.java:479)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.addSourceObjectType(BcelWorld.java:453)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.addClassFile(BcelWeaver.java:456)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.addClassFile(BcelWeaver.java:480)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.initBcelWorld(AjBuildManager.java:908)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.performBuild(AjBuildManager.java:253)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.batchBuild(AjBuildManager.java:189)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.ajc.AjdtCommand.doCommand(AjdtCommand.java:114)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.ajc.AjdtCommand.runCommand(AjdtCommand.java:60)
    at org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main.run(Main.java:371)
    at com.archinamon.api.AspectJWeaver$doWeave$2.invoke(AspectJWeaver.kt:128)
    at com.archinamon.api.AspectJWeaver$doWeave$2.invoke(AspectJWeaver.kt:14)
    at com.archinamon.api.AspectJWeaver$Companion.runBlocking(AspectJWeaver.kt:182)
    at com.archinamon.api.AspectJWeaver.doWeave$android_gradle_aspectj(AspectJWeaver.kt:126)
    at com.archinamon.api.transform.AspectJTransform.transform(AspectJTransform.kt:182)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:284)
[...]
```

### Used Gradle configuration

Here's a reduced version of my build.gradle files:

project level:

```
buildscript {
    [...]
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1"
        [...]
        classpath "com.archinamon:android-gradle-aspectj:4.2.1"
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3"
        classpath "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.2.0"
        classpath "com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.3.1"
    }
}
[...]
```

app level:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
[...]
apply plugin: 'com.archinamon.aspectj'

[...]

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    [...]
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.4"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:17.4.4"
    implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.1.1"
    implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.7"
    [...]
}
```

### Investigation

[Firebase-perf conflicting with let plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54888254/firebase-perf-conflicting-with-let-plugin)

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/770

I've tried the approaches mentioned there, but they did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the order of the plugins matters. Applying the AspectJ plugin before the Firebase plugins in the app level build.gradle solved my issue:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.archinamon.aspectj'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
[...]
```